# How to delete a file asynchronously

Tags: java, file, asynchronous, delete-file

At the below, it deletes file asynchronously with EJB injection.

```
@Asynchronous
protected void deleteFileAsync(File file) {
    if (file != null)
        file.delete();
}
```

Is it possible to delete a file asynchronously without using any annotations
and EJB injection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working with file system from EJB is bad practice, because file system is not transactional.

Yes, it is possible to delete file asynchronously: do it in separate thread. You can create separate thread by your own, something like this:

```
public static void deleteFile(final File file) {
    if (file != null) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                file.delete();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

But if you will invoke this function from loop, you will create a lot of  uncontrollable threads which will waste you memory. You can avoid this using **Executors**. Using this utility classes you can create thread pool with single thread, which will serve all your file deletion tasks:

```
private static final ExecutorService DELETE_SERVICE = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public static void deleteFile(final File file) {
    if (file != null) {
        DELETE_SERVICE.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                file.delete();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here you will have one thread, which will delete files asynchronously.

Comment: +1 for Executors. If you create more than one thread or use an executor that isn't single-threaded, don't forget to make it thread safe using a lock or synchronized block

Comment: It's generally not a good practice to manually spawn threads in a Java EE application server, since resources (like threads) are supposed to be managed by the app server. Instead of using `Executors`, it would be better use the Java EE version, by injecting `@Resource ManagedExecutorService`

Comment: @sh0rug0ru Yes, of course, but ManagedExecutorService is available only with Java EE 7 compatible application servers.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mention JavaEE 7? Whoops. In any case, the EJB 2.1 spec (since J2EE 1.3) specifically states "The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage threads. The enterprise bean must not attempt to start, stop, suspend, or resume a thread, or to change a thread’s priority or name. The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage thread groups." The JavaEE app server provides ways of managing work asynchronously, and if you are using an app server at all, it is better to use what the app server provides.

Comment: @sh0rug0ru, so do you suggest me to use 'asynchronous' as I write in my question?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest stick with `@Asynchronous` and other standard APIs, unless and until the standard fails you. You're in JavaEE land, it's better to go with the grain than against it.